# Memory leak when using Google Test on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, memory-leaks, googletest

When I run the following code:

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <crtdbg.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following output:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{652} normal block at 0x00074CE0, 4 bytes long.
 Data: < L  > 98 4C 07 00 
{651} normal block at 0x00074C98, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <,           > 2C 03 1B 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
{650} normal block at 0x00074C50, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <hI      > 68 49 07 00 00 00 00 00 
{649} normal block at 0x00074C10, 4 bytes long.
 Data: <t   > 74 03 1B 01 
{648} normal block at 0x00074BC8, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <xK      > 78 4B 07 00 00 00 00 00 
{647} normal block at 0x00074B70, 28 bytes long.
 Data: <         K   L  > BC 01 1B 01 01 CD CD CD C8 4B 07 00 E0 4C 07 00 
{646} normal block at 0x00074B28, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < I      > 18 49 07 00 00 00 00 00 
{645} normal block at 0x00074AE0, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < I      > 04 49 07 00 00 00 00 00 
{644} normal block at 0x00074A98, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < H      > DC 48 07 00 00 00 00 00 
{643} normal block at 0x00074A50, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < H      > C8 48 07 00 00 00 00 00 
{642} normal block at 0x00074A08, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < H      > B4 48 07 00 00 00 00 00 
{641} normal block at 0x000749C0, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < H      > A0 48 07 00 00 00 00 00 
{640} normal block at 0x00074E90, 1 bytes long.
 Data: < > 00 
{639} normal block at 0x00074870, 272 bytes long.
 Data: <        t    N  > 20 03 1B 01 CD CD CD CD 74 FA 1B 01 90 4E 07 00 
{638} normal block at 0x00074F68, 72 bytes long.
 Data: <C:\Users\Baz> 43 3A 5C 55 73 65 72 73 5C 45 42 41 52 47 52 49 
{637} normal block at 0x00074E48, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <hO  G   > 68 4F 07 00 47 00 00 00 
{616} normal block at 0x00074EE0, 72 bytes long.
 Data: <C:\Users\Baz> 43 3A 5C 55 73 65 72 73 5C 45 42 41 52 47 52 49 
{595} normal block at 0x00074828, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <        > F0 F9 1B 01 00 00 00 00 
{594} normal block at 0x000747E8, 1 bytes long.
 Data: < > 00 
{561} normal block at 0x000747A0, 5 bytes long.
 Data: <fast > 66 61 73 74 00 
{496} normal block at 0x00074760, 1 bytes long.
 Data: < > 00 
{311} normal block at 0x00074720, 1 bytes long.
 Data: < > 00 
{282} normal block at 0x000746E0, 2 bytes long.
 Data: <* > 2A 00 
{253} normal block at 0x00074698, 5 bytes long.
 Data: <auto > 61 75 74 6F 00 
Object dump complete.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. The 'memory leaks' come from heap allocations of the statically initialized google test singleton class.

Here's the answer from google tests FAQ: [How do I suppress the memory leak messages on Windows?](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/faq.md#how-do-i-suppress-the-memory-leak-messages-on-windows)

Answer (score 6):

Adding to the accepted answer, the Google [documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/faq.md#how-do-i-suppress-the-memory-leak-messages-on-windows) states:

> Since the statically initialized Google Test singleton requires allocations on the heap, the Visual C++ memory leak detector will report memory leaks at the end of the program run. The easiest way to avoid this is to use the _CrtMemCheckpoint and _CrtMemDumpAllObjectsSince calls to not report any statically initialized heap objects. See MSDN for more details and additional heap check/debug routines.

This involves calling [_CrtMemCheckPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h3z85t43.aspx) just after `::testing::InitGoogleTest` and then calling [_CrtMemDumpAllObjectsSince](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhy09244.aspx) after `RUN_ALL_TESTS()`.  The main function looks a bit like this:

```
::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, &argv);
// Get a checkpoint of the memory after Google Test has been initialized.
_CrtMemState memoryState = {0};
_CrtMemCheckpoint( &memoryState );
int retval = RUN_ALL_TESTS();

// Check for leaks after tests have run
_CrtMemDumpAllObjectsSince( &memoryState );
return retval;
```

Unfortunately, if a test fails Google test causes a memory leak, which means this isn't a perfect solution.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not enough, on gtest-1.7.0 there are allocations in gtest made within RUN_ALL_TESTS which are not freed, check `UnitTestImpl::os_stack_trace_getter` for example

Comment: As @kerim mentions, the _CrtMemCheckpoint approach alone is not sufficient due to static allocations performed in `UnitTestImpl::os_stack_trace_getter`.

My hacky workaround was to always execute a dummy test before the memory checkpoint.  This adds one extra preamble test, but at least I can check for leaks.

Tip: You can use `::testing::GTEST_FLAG(filter) = "DummyTestName*"` to execute just the dummy test, and then `::testing::GTEST_FLAG(filter) = "-DummyTestName*"` to exclude it when running the rest.